# Saving CMD output to text file after program finish running

Tags: java, windows, cmd, command, volatility

Is there any ways to save the final output from command prompt to a text file after the program finished running? I have tried it with ProcessBuilder and it does not work. (Reason because my output does not appear immediately, it goes through a short processing time before the output is loaded onto the command prompt screen) in java.

```
String command = "cmd /c start cmd /k E:\\vol231.exe -f E:\\KOHMOHOJOJO-PC-20140714-152414.raw imageinfo > output.txt";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

[image]
[image]

It actually takes around 2-5 mins for it to process.

I referred to several websites but it still does not work. Any help given will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try save output with java code:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(p.getInputStream(), writer, encoding);
String theString = writer.toString();
```

Also error stream can be saved with class "ProcessBuilder"